# ActiveRecord joins add where to having clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following query which works well. However, I'd like to specify a condition on the through table that the `replier_fb_group` column `removed_on` is null

```
groups = FbGroup.joins(:replier_accounts).where(
  id: group_ids,
  :replier_accounts => { active: true }
 ).group('fb_groups.id'
 ).having('count(replier_accounts) > 0')
```

What I tried

```
FbGroup.joins(:replier_fb_groups, :replier_accounts).where(
  id: group_ids,
  :replier_fb_groups => { removed_on: nil},
  :replier_accounts => { active: true }
).group('fb_groups.id'
).having('count(replier_accounts) > 0')
```

How can i make it so in the having clause, you are only counting `replier_accounts` that pass the condition of their `replier_fb_group`'s having the condition of `removed_on` be nil?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way to join `FbGroup` to `ReplierAccounts` THROUGH `ReplierFbGroups`. Here, I'm assuming that `ReplierFbGroups` is a table that contains `ids` of both, `FbGroup` and `ReplierAccounts` as foreign keys. (Please let me know in case that is an incorrect assumption).

In order to fetch the data you need, you may have to write a query as follows:

```
FbGroup
  .joins(replier_fb_groups: : replier_accounts)
  .where("replier_accounts.active = true AND replier_fb_groups.removed_on IS NULL")
  .group("fb_groups.id")
  .having("count(replier_accounts) > 0")
```

Here, if you notice the join carefully, we perform a [join on a nested association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level) as `.joins(replier_fb_groups: : replier_accounts)` instead of a join of FbGroups [with multiple tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-multiple-associations) independently as `.joins(:replier_fb_groups, : replier_accounts)`

NOTE: This could further be enhanced by using [merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to merge conditions from `replier_accounts` and `replier_fb_groups`. That would be something like:

```
FbGroup
  .joins(replier_fb_groups: : replier_accounts)
  .merge(ReplierAccount.active)
  .merge(ReplierFbGroup.not_removed)
  .group("fb_groups.id")
  .having("count(replier_accounts) > 0")
```

where `ReplierAccount.active` and `ReplierFbGroup.not_removed` are scopes on the respective models to apply the active and not removed conditions respectively.